# Android Studio, gradle.build syntax in windows and linux

Tags: android, linux, windows

I have some projects hosted in github and I have a question. In my home I use Ubuntu, but in my work I have to use Windows 10.

There are some syntax differences in the gradle.build file depending on the OS being used. Is there any kind of IFDEF that can be used to identify the OS and resolve these issues?

For example, my keystore folder in linux is completelly different than the windows one.